# Why does calling a functor with an undeclared variable work?

Tags: c++, compilation, functor, most-vexing-parse

```
class foo {
    public:
    bool operator () (int & i) {
        return true;
    }
};

int main() {
    foo(WhyDoesThisCompile);
    return 0;
}
```

When passing `WhyDoesThisCompile` (without spaces) to the functor, the program compiles.

Why is this? I tested it on clang 4.0.0.

Comment: @TheGreatDuck there is no foo function... foo is a class. please read accepted answer

Comment: @TheGreatDuck no. there is no other function called foo. this code compiles as is. see https://godbolt.org/g/4tZAS0 for example

Comment: @TheGreatDuck dude, it is not a defaut constructor call. did you even read the answer? "You are declaring a foo, called WhyDoesThisCompile.
Yes, despite the parentheses" see my link to compiler explorer to prove that it compiles.

Comment: @TheGreatDuck again. see link https://godbolt.org/g/4tZAS0

Comment: @TheGreatDuck why would a constructor accept a "WhyDoesThisCompile" when it doesnt exist."Foo(WhyDoesThisCompile)" == "Foo WhyDoesThisCompile;"

Comment: @TheGreatDuck i still don't think you understand. this should clear things up https://godbolt.org/g/ZbfqrB

Comment: @TheGreatDuck your comments make no sense. Default constructors don't accept "a type of undeclared variable" (whatever that is even supposed to mean)

Comment: @TheGreatDuck the lack of understanding isn't that what you're saying isn't clear, it's that it's **clearly 100% wrong** and you keep repeating it in the face of evidence, and it's hard to understand **why** you keep insisting on adding incorrect nonsense to a question that's already been adequately answered.

Comment: @TheGreatDuck: No, it is the syntax of a declaration, as has now been explained and demonstrated multiple times. There is no function call here whatsoever. And, no, there is no such thing as type "undefined" in C++. Where did you hear that there is?

Comment: @TheGreatDuck there is no such type as "undefined" in C++ ; and the syntax `a(b)` has several possible meanings depending what `a` and `b` are. Also there is no built-in function called `foo`. You must just be trolling at this point

Comment: @TheGreatDuck: Which is (a) completely irrelevant, and (b) not what you were claiming

Comment: @TheGreatDuck: No, it isn't. I shall now quote you: _"Where is this 'foo' function that you are calling?" " You miss my point. Somewhere in the code, you have made a function call to a function called foo" "Dude... you're either invoking the default constructor or something within the C++ language. That is definitely a function call." "There is a function somewhere. It is probable just an implicitly defined function." "I'm saying it is a call to the default constructor." "it's the syntax of a function call. Clearly c++ is intending it to mean something in terms of function calling."_

Comment: @TheGreatDuck: _(cont.)_ _"There is such a thing as type 'undefined' in c++" "How could there not be an undefined type? How else does c++ recognize when something is undefined..."_ These are your claims, and every single one of them is wrong.

Comment: @TheGreatDuck: The... "declaration operator"? What are you prattling on about now?

Comment: Then I guess we have nothing further to say. I shall simply refer to you all the above responses to your nonsensical claims! Good night

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You are not invoking the functor.

**You are declaring a `foo`, called `WhyDoesThisCompile`.**

Yes, despite the parentheses.

---

I guess you meant this:

```
   foo()(WhyDoesThisCompile);
// ^^^^^
// temp ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
//  of   invocation of op()
// type
// `foo`
```

… which doesn't.

Comment: so this is the same as, code -> "foo WhyDoesThisCompile;" ? if so, i find that really odd.

Comment: Insanely confusing and counter-intuitive. Didn't believe it was legal C++.

Comment: @BoundaryImposition I ran into this syntax accedentally i was confused that it was still compiling, thanks for the answer!

Comment: @DanielCollier: No problem - enjoy the bank hol!

Comment: Any idea which part of the standard grammar makes this possible? I can't seem to locate it.

Comment: @DanielCollier, The syntax comes from C, but in general, you can put extra parentheses in declarations. You sometimes need them, too, if not using type aliases or other tricks: `int(&arr)[2];` or `void(*f)(int);`

Comment: Every few weeks, we get one of those ambiguity/vexing parse questions :)

Comment: @DeiDei see [dcl.decl]/4 where it gives the grammar for declarations - a `noptr-declarator` is a `ptr-declarator`, and `( ptr-declarator )` is a `noptr-declarator`, which is saying that you can put parentheses around any declarator. For example `int *p;` and `int (((*(((((p))))))));` are the same

Comment: Just when I thought I knew everything about C++ syntax...